# facebook login button click fails when facebook app isn't installed

Tags: java, android, facebook-login, noclassdeffounderror, chrome-custom-tabs

My facebook login button works alright when the facebook app is installed.

When the facebook app isn't installed on the device, it crashes my app:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: 
Landroid/support/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent$Builder;
at com.facebook.internal.CustomTab.openCustomTab(CustomTab.java:47)
at com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity.onCreate(CustomTabMainActivity.java:67)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent$Builder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.testapp-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.testapp-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com.testapp-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
at com.facebook.internal.CustomTab.openCustomTab(CustomTab.java:47) 
at com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity.onCreate(CustomTabMainActivity.java:67) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent$Builder
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

**MANIFEST:**

```
<activity
    android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

while fb_login_protocol_scheme value starts with "fb" as needed.

**Gradle dependencies:**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.1'
    compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.20.0') // app invites
    {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.20.0'
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.0"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**How can I solve it?**

Answer (score 19):

You are excluding 'com.android.support' from the facebook dependency. I assume it is because it wasn't including the same version of support libraries as you are (facebook sdk 4.20.0 uses android:support:25.0.0 but you include support libraries 25.3.0, so excluding it is the right thing to do).

But if you want to have the CustomTab feature working, you therefore must include the appropriate dependency in your app dependencies, so add the following line :

```
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.0'
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Add these two dependencies:

```
implementation('com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }

implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency in build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
```